# Having trouble importing data with sets in SAS

Tags: sas

```
data testData;                    
   INFILE DATALINES;
   INPUT crop $ 1-11 [month1] 12-23 [month2] 25-36 [month3] 38-49;     
   datalines;         
   Corn       16 27 31 33  15 23 30 30  16 27 27 26  
   Corn       18 20 25 23  15 15 31 32  15 32 32 15  
   Corn       12 15 16 73  . . . .      . . . . 
   Soybeans   20 23 23 25  24 24 25 32  21 25 23 24  
   Soybeans   27 45 24 12  12 13 15 42  22 32 31 43  
   Cotton     31 32 33 34  29 24 26 28  34 32 28 45  
   Cotton     26 25 23 24  53 48 75 26  34 35 25 78  
   Sugarbeets 22 23 25 42  25 25 24 26  34 25 16 52  
   Sugarbeets 54 23 21 54  25 43 32 15  26 54  2 54  
   Clover     12 45 32 54  24 58 25 34  87 54 61 21  
   Clover     51 31 31 16  96 48 54 62  31 31 11 11  
   Clover     56 13 13 71  32 13 27 32  36 26 54 32  
   Clover     53 08 06 54  32 32 62 16  . . . .
;
```

I don't have much guidance on what this data actually is (it's a school question) so I'm assuming that the number sets are harvests per week per month. I'm fairly new to SAS so I might be going in the complete wrong direction, but I thought tossing the months in arrays would be the best bet. I added the periods because there is some missing data.

The issue with this code is that I get this error:

```
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.  

ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: NAME.
```

But it seems like the [month1] should be naming the array, right? I've also tried this:

```
data testData;                    
   INFILE DATALINES;
   array crop{*} $ 1-11;
   array month1{*} 12-23;
   array month2{*} 25-36;
   array month3{*} 38-49;
   datalines;         
   Corn       16 27 31 33  15 23 30 30  16 27 27 26  
   Corn       18 20 25 23  15 15 31 32  15 32 32 15  
   Corn       12 15 16 73  . . . .      . . . . 
   Soybeans   20 23 23 25  24 24 25 32  21 25 23 24  
   Soybeans   27 45 24 12  12 13 15 42  22 32 31 43  
   Cotton     31 32 33 34  29 24 26 28  34 32 28 45  
   Cotton     26 25 23 24  53 48 75 26  34 35 25 78  
   Sugarbeets 22 23 25 42  25 25 24 26  34 25 16 52  
   Sugarbeets 54 23 21 54  25 43 32 15  26 54  2 54  
   Clover     12 45 32 54  24 58 25 34  87 54 61 21  
   Clover     51 31 31 16  96 48 54 62  31 31 11 11  
   Clover     56 13 13 71  32 13 27 32  36 26 54 32  
   Clover     53 08 06 54  32 32 62 16  . . . .
;
```

I'm not sure which method I should be using or if I'm even going in the right direction with this dataset.

Comment: Show the exact data as defined in the question.  Also show the full text of the question.

Comment: The repeated data for a crop indicates you might be missing some additional information such as YEAR, or FIELD_ID, or FARM_ID

Comment: @data_null_ That is the full data set and the question is just "Use PROC LOGISTIC with a score statement to score the following data:". Which is why I was confused about the data

Answer (score 2):

For what I can tell you have crop value for 12 separate time points - so twelve months?
In the input statement you just need to define a variable name for all your columns which you are providing in your "datalines" statement. This can just be defined as:

```
data testData;                    
   INFILE DATALINES;
   Input Crop $ month1-month12;
   datalines;         
   Corn       16 27 31 33  15 23 30 30  16 27 27 26  
   Corn       18 20 25 23  15 15 31 32  15 32 32 15  
   Corn       12 15 16 73  . . . .      . . . . 
   Soybeans   20 23 23 25  24 24 25 32  21 25 23 24  
   Soybeans   27 45 24 12  12 13 15 42  22 32 31 43  
   Cotton     31 32 33 34  29 24 26 28  34 32 28 45  
   Cotton     26 25 23 24  53 48 75 26  34 35 25 78  
   Sugarbeets 22 23 25 42  25 25 24 26  34 25 16 52  
   Sugarbeets 54 23 21 54  25 43 32 15  26 54  2 54  
   Clover     12 45 32 54  24 58 25 34  87 54 61 21  
   Clover     51 31 31 16  96 48 54 62  31 31 11 11  
   Clover     56 13 13 71  32 13 27 32  36 26 54 32  
   Clover     53 08 06 54  32 32 62 16  . . . .;
run;
```

Arrays are used to refer to already existing variables, so to my knowledge not to declare variables as you want to do here.

Comment: You can define/declare variables using an array statement.  In many cases you can use the array to refer to all of the elements at once.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah the numbers being one each month makes more since that three months. I just assumed three months because there were double spaces after each four numbers.